# Segmentation fault occurs when a C++ program is reading a file while a separate python GUI script is writing to the same file

Tags: python, c++, c++14

I am currently running this on Raspbian OS - Debian.

I have two separate programs running in unison. I have a c++ 'engine' and a python 'gui' interface. I know there is probably a much better practice, but at the moment they are communicating via flat files. Essentially the python GUI writes to a file, `cmd.sf`, with specific text and the engine then decodes that exact same file and executes whatever it needs to do.

The setup is quite simple:

#### C++ Engine:

The C++ program is constantly reading the `cmd.sf` file and stays in an infinite loop within the engine if the context of the file is `-1`. The moment the file changes the engine should parse what the Python GUI essentially wrote and upon successful execution of whatever the contents told the engine to do, it writes back to the file `-1`

#### Python GUI

On the GUI end, it's the same concept except it is reversed. GUI also constantly reads from the `cmd.sf` file and doesn't proceed with writing the same or different instruction until it knows the C++ engine is done with its previous instruction. So it essentially checks the file to make sure it is anything BUT `-1`

The problem lies where if I initially set `cmd.sf` to `-1`, the C++ engine does what it needs to do successfully, by constantly reading and checking the contents of the file. However, the moment I instruct the GUI to change the file's contents, the C++ engine hangs, spits out a seg fault, and aborts.

However, I have found something that does work and I can not for the life of me figure out why. If I was to open `cmd.sf` in a text-editor such as geany (I am Raspbian) and change the contents via the editor and save it, it does not cause a segfault error. In fact the C++ engine notices the change of the file contents, executes the instruction appropriately and write `-1` back to the file. It seems to not like it when I programatically change the contents of the file.

Here is a snippet of my python code that changes the contents of the file, this is nested in a loop:

```py
scan_cmd = AllCommands.start_scan

# generate the key cmd packet for engine to start listening to incoming switches

#
# with open("../data/switches_debug.sf") as sw_file:
#    switch_ids = [i.split(",")[0] for i in sw_file.readlines()]
#    #print(switch_ids)

packet = CommandPacket(0xFFFFFF, scan_cmd)
content = ""




can_edit_file = False
while not can_edit_file:
    with open("../data/cmd.sf", "r") as cmd_file:
        try:
            content = int(cmd_file.readlines()[0])
        except ValueError:
        # means gui has already written to file and is in the form of x,x,x,...,x
        # 12345,67,8
        # The beginning of this function should just check to see if
        # file content IS NOT -1 in order to prevent engine and gui
        # writing to the file at the same time
        #
        # So if GUI has written to file and in the
        # form of csv, it is obviously not -1
        #
        # assign content a value that is not -1
        content = 0

        if content == -1:
            can_edit_file = True

msg = "Begin Listening... [%s]" % packet.hex()
print(msg)
content = ','.join(str(x) for x in packet.plist)

# open as 'w' to overrite content of file
with open("../data/cmd.sf", "w") as cmd_file:
    cmd_file.write(content)

print("Wrote [%s] to ../data/cmd.sf" % packet.hex())
```

Similarly, this is the C++ code that reads and checks if the file has changed:

```cpp
Scribe Cher("../data/cmd.sf");

for (;;) {
    std::cout << std::flush;
    // cpu_timer tmr;

    // loop forever and read from cmd.sf for instructions
    // if file contents is != -1 instruction from GUI is set; read and execute
    // upon successful instruction execution write '-1' to file

    // read contents of cmd.sf file
    bool file_is_ready = false;
    int u = 0;
    do{

      Cher.ReadFile();    // custome object that actually does the reading
      cmd_file = std::stoi(Cher.FileContents);   // Cher.FileContents is std::string

      //debugging section
      if(u % 10000 == 0){
    std::cout << std::flush;
    fmt::printf("File Contents: {%s}\n", Cher.FileContents);
      }

      if(cmd_file != -1){
    file_is_ready = true;
      }
      u++;

    }while(!file_is_ready);
}
```

The Cher instance is of object Scribe with is a helper class that controls reading/writing to files. Upon initialization, it sets one important member within the class and that is the path to file.. each "Scribe" is assigned to one file.

```cpp
void Scribe::ReadFile(){
  std::string file_contents;
  std::vector<std::string> vstring;

  this->File.close();   //in case the file is opened
  if(!this->File.open(std::ios::in)){
    throw std::ios::failure("Unable to open file.");
    //std::cout << "Unable to Open" << std::endl;
  }

  this->File.clear();
  this->File.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

  while(this->File >> file_contents){
    std::cout << "infinite loop" << std::endl;
    vstring.push_back(file_contents);
  }

//for(auto &i: vstring){
// std::cout << i << std::endl;
//
  this->FileContents = vstring[0];
  this->File.close();
}
```

Here is an example stdout output from the terminal when I run this by initially setting the `cmd.sf` to `-1`

```sh
File Contents: -1
File Contents: -1
File Contents: -1
File Contents: -1
File Contents: -1
File Contents: -1
File Contents: -1
File Contents: -1
File Contents: -1
File Contents: -1
File Contents: -1
Segmentation Fault     //this is when I use the python gui to change file contents
```

Comment: Maybe try and open the file with lock in Python, i.e. fcntl.flock(open('../data/cmd.sf', 'w'), fcntl.LOCK_EX). I don't know if that works on your platform.

Comment: @J.R. Unfortuantly pip doesn’t seem to find fcntl module on Raspbian os :(

Comment: Does import not work? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14206/locking-a-python-script-on-my-pi

Comment: @J.R. No my current pip list does not contain fcntl and pip doesn’t show any modules available. I have already updated to the latest pip and tried on pip and pip3